# Make text SEO friendly

Tags: asp.net, seo

I have following popup html structure in aspx page(asp.net) which i made hide and show on a link click using jquery but this is not SEO friendly.How can i make it SEO friendly without using meta tags?

```
<div class="popupbackground" id="divDescription" style="display: block;">
            <div style="display: block;" class="width" id="divDescriptionPopup">
            <div style="margin-top: -200px;" class="popup">
                <div class="close float-right">
                    <a style="float: right;
                        display: inline" onclick="return CloseDescription_Close();"   href="" id="CloseDescription">
                        <img title="Close" alt="Close" src="../Images/close.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <h3 class="float-left heading">
                    Description</h3>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
                <div class="popup_inner_description">
                    <div class="pop_scroll">
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblLongDescription"><font size="3"><span style="font-weight: bold;">content here.... <span style="font-weight: bold;">SavingON.co.uk</span> content here....<br><br> content here....<br><br>content here <br><br>content here...</span></font></span>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not that I'm saying your wrong, but if you know its not SEO friendly, why is that?

Comment: I have no idea how this pop-up related with SEO? Only thing that I can see in this from is adding a proper **alt** tab for the image you using and adding proper keyword in the description !!!

Comment: Font tags?! Welcome to the 90s. What is not SEO friendly about it?

Comment: There are font and span tags to style content because the content is being formatted with nicEditor.

Comment: Some inline styling might be inevitable if you are using 3rd-party tools, but surely it can be configured to use `style="font-size:120%;"` rather than the deprecated FONT tag?

Comment: You couldn't SEO a popup dialog even if you wanted to! If your goal is to optimise the parent page (which loads the popup) then work on that page itself. 
Popups will never show on Search Results for any keyword/terms

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the deprecated FONT tag that Kevin pointed out, and perhaps a little too much in-line CSS, there is nothing wrong with this could that would stop your page being crawled easily.

Even if set to `display:none;`, although the content would not be visible to a human visitor, it would be visible to bots.

And even if there were an issue, I'm not sure what help you would expect to get from meta tags...

Perhaps if you could explain a little more about what you think the problem is and how you came to this conclusion....

Comment: The main issue is the content/text in span having id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblLongDescription" is not SEO friendly means not comes in google search result.

Comment: The cleaner your code is, the more favourably SEs will look upon it, but having content inside a SPAN isn't going to particularly harm you. A SPAN is just another structural element that SEs will largely ignore. Nobody know exactly how SEs rank pages, but I've seen nothing around that I think you should particularly worry about - if your content is worthwhile, the bots will take note and you will get listed.

Answer (score 0):

The main intent of seo friendly means "user friendly".

You should appear all data like content, image, link etc.. for user, which is profitable to user, so google consider your website is for user OR seo friendly, not only for bot.

Google main intent is your website must informative for user, so google give user best information, which is find from google.

Answer (score 0):

Their are some steps to make your site seo friendly :-
Integrate Social Media into your Website’s Design
Use seo images too
Make sure your url is user friendly 
Place your keywords in many different places